# What does it mean to unpack a parameter pack into another template declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand how the following feature should be used. When I call `A::f` I can omit the template parameters, but I don't understand why.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct A
{
    template <Args...>
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    A<int, bool> a;
    a.f();
}
```

To be specific, what does the `template <Args...>` mean and why can I leave the template parameters out of the function call to `f`?

Comment: It means it expands to `template<int, bool>` because that's what you made `Args` when instantiating the class. I'm not entirely sure how it compiles, though, since actually changing it to `template<int, bool>` doesn't.

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug

Comment: ... and it should be used like this, but it can't: http://ideone.com/gAQEox (Note: With `template<Args...>` being expanded to `template<int, bool>`, it's fine: http://ideone.com/Q70BzL)

Comment: Now I'm curious. Did you find code like this somewhere? You're question just reads like you saw a similar piece of code and couldn't explain what it does / *why* you should write `template<Args...>`.

Comment: @leemes I think I found the code in a PDF file on C++11. I just rewrote what I remember seeing (it wasn't exactly this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`template<typename ...Args>` is  a variadic template. It means, that you can specify any number of template type parameters, but I think you already know this.

Whenever `Args...` appears in the template code, it will be **unpacked** ("expanded") to the **types** of the instantiation. In your example, this is **`int, bool`**. So your class becomes, when fully expanded, this definition:

```
struct A<int, bool>
{
    template <int, bool>
    void f() {}
};
```

This means, `A<int,bool>::f()` is again templated (the arguments are unpacked *into another template declaration*, as you called it), but this time with *non-type* template parameters with the types `int` and `bool` (they're anonymous), so you could instantiate `f()` for example like this:

```
a.f<1, true>();
```

Unfortunately, `g++` seems to have a bug and [won't accept](http://ideone.com/gAQEox) this piece of code, while it [accepts](http://ideone.com/Q70BzL) your code.

`clang` accepts both codes. I expect that in your code, clang doesn't care if the `int` and `bool` template parameters are omitted, but it doesn't complain either when they are specified (in contrast to `g++`).

**Usage example:**

If you want to use the specified values, they can't be anonymous (obviously). You can, for example, provide a format string in `f()` which is used to "printf" the template values, like this:

```
template <Args ...values>
void f(const char *fmt) {
    std::printf(fmt, values...);
}
```

Then, the following code

```
A<int> a;
a.f<42>("The answer is %d!\n");
```

will print:

```
The answer is 42!
```

But, using the syntax from above (`Args...` being expanded to anonymous non-type template parameters), the template parameters are essentially **useless**.

Without specifying values, it still compiles (which surprised me!) and prints an uninitialized `int` value.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering why `a.f<1, true>()` wasn't compiling :)

Comment: It's a known bug in clang aswell that it allows you to omit it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yeah I guessed so. It just doesn't make sense to allow to omit non-default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can leave the template arguments out is because c++11 has template argument deduction `template<args ...>` is a variadic template which is basically a pack of possibly different typenames. This [website](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/template_argument_deduction.htm) explains the omission of template arguments. From reading further into the deduction of non type template arguments, which the compiler can deduce I believe that the compiler is realizing that they are never used (with clang at least) and making it's deduction based on that, read the deducing non type template arguments portion of the [website](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/template_argument_deduction.htm)

Comment: But there is nothing there to deduce the parameters from, since they're non-type parameters `template<int,bool>`

Comment: well in his example there are no types, the bool and the int are part of the class template not the function template

Comment: `f` is a template function. It's templated with two *values* of type int and bool, because `template<Args...>` expands to `template<int,bool>`.